# Parse a string with placeholders into an array with PHP

Tags: php, wildcard, string-parsing

I have a string that like

```
$input = '%name (%postcode) <%email>';
```

How can I detect the placeholders with the scheme `%NAME` so that I get an array

```
$wildcards = array('name', 'postcode', 'email');
```

in the end?

It should recognize any wildcards following the wildcard scheme in any string. So the function should also convert

```
'%address (%name)'
```

to

```
array('address', 'name')
```

The wildcard scheme is not fixed, so if you have a better solution those can be changed. I fiddled around with `sscanf()`, but as the format of the input string varies I need something more flexible and it did not suit my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
$input = '%name (%postcode) <%email>';
preg_match_all('/%(\w+)/', $input, $m);
$wildcards = $m[1];
print_r($wildcards);
```

#### Outut:

```
Array
(
    [0] => name
    [1] => postcode
    [2] => email
)
```